# Open HTA file in IE without Save/Open/Cancel prompt in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hta

Is there a way i could open a HTA file in IE without being prompted to save/open/cancel using C# and WindowsForms?
Here's how I do it, with the prompt showing up:

```
Process.Start("iexplore", Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "file.hta"));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTAs are run by explorer.exe, not by browser (iexplore.exe), so you can try this:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "file.hta"));
```

or:

```
Process.Start("mshta.exe", Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "file.hta"));
```